# Allure not generating a report from Robotframework output

Tags: robotframework, allure

I've robotframework(python), allure, and the pytest allure adaptor installed.

**pytest-allure-adaptor (1.7.9)**

**robotframework-allurereport (1.1.1)**

**allure --version 2.4.1**

When I run pybot with the Allure listener an xml file is generated. However running allure generate on this generates an error:

**allure generate --clean**

```
Could not read result allure-results/7c28854b-7ac2-497b-89b0-f312427db7db-testsuite.xml: {}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.SeverityLevel` from String "None": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [trivial, blocker, minor, normal, critical]
 at [Source: (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 6, column: 5] (through reference chain: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.TestSuiteResult["test-cases"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.TestCaseResult["severity"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1535)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:910)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer._deserializeAltString(EnumDeserializer.java:255)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:179)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at io.qameta.allure.allure1.ListDeserializer.deserialize(ListDeserializer.java:56)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3058)
        at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.readXmlTestSuiteFile(Allure1Plugin.java:432)
        at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin$$Lambda$42/536122141.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.readResults(Allure1Plugin.java:116)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.lambda$readResults$0(ReportGenerator.java:32)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator$$Lambda$35/2012993836.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.readResults(ReportGenerator.java:32)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator$$Lambda$32/1499136125.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:54)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:43)
        at io.qameta.allure.Commands.generate(Commands.java:88)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:129)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine$$Lambda$1/2096057945.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:72)
Report successfully generated to allure-report
```

**cd allure-report**

ls -lrt

```
1638751 Nov 17 16:16 styles.css

306 Nov 17 16:16 plugins

647 Nov 17 16:16 index.html

136 Nov 17 16:16 history

860 Nov 17 16:16 favicon.ico

136 Nov 17 16:16 export

374 Nov 17 16:16 data

680472 Nov 17 16:16 app.js
```

index.html opens but contains all 404 links. 
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Your allure version is too new, you need to use version 2.0.0 (at least is the one that works for us!)